# Contact form 7 CF7 recipient-email from hidden field in page

Tags: wordpress

I'm stuck on this:

I have a wordpress membership page (made with indeed membership pro) where visitors can fill out a CF7 form that should be sent to member e-mail.
This value is stored in that page, in an hidden input value:

```
<input type="hidden" name="recipient-email" value="recipient-email@domain.com">
```

and it's also in a membership pro shortcode:

```
{CUSTOM_FIELD_recipient_email}
```

Is there a way to add this value into CF7 recipient-email?

I also tried with CF7 DTX but it's not getting the dynamic value.

Thanks a lot!